# What can make a macro run well when executed directly but fail when called from a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have several macros I created in Access. The macro works well when executing it by double clicking on its name.

Recently, I have created several forms to act as a GUI for the database, with buttons that when click call the macros and execute them.

Most of the problems occur at the action EmailDatabaseObject. Before sending the mail, the macros delete a table and import data into it.

I insist, when double clicking them they work perfectly.

The two errors that have appeared so far are 3066 and 2306. They not always appear.

Answer (score 0):

The two errors are very different - the first indicates that there is a query that isn't returning any data.

The second indicates that there are too *many* rows being returned to allow the creation of a output file. e.g over 16,000 if it's exporting to an old version of excel.

As these are in macro's they are pretty difficult to fault find - why don't you covert them to VBA and post up the code. Or maybe at least post up the number of records and or query SQL to see what's happening.